# Error: exec proxy not found for :: SpeechRecognition :: hasPermission

Tags: browser, cordova-plugins, speech-recognition, ionic5

const options = {
language: 'en-US',
showPopup: false,
audioFile: file_path
};
this.speechRecognition.hasPermission()
.then((hasPermission: boolean) => {
console.log(hasPermission)
if (!hasPermission) {
this.speechRecognition.requestPermission()
.then(
() => console.log('granted'),
() => console.log('Denied')
)
}
})

I’m trying to use cordova speech recognition plugin in ionic cordova platform browser Error: exec proxy not found for :: SpeechRecognition :: hasPermission